# iOS in-App Purchase failure due to "Strong customer authentication transactions in European Economic Area"

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

In our iOS app, in-App purchase(auto-renewable subscriptions) was working very well, but from January this year due to some unknown reason in-App purchase getting failed for European Customers mainly from country "Denmark".

For "Strong customer authentication transactions in European Economic Area" , Now users are moved to outside of the App for Strong Authentication as per new European law (ref: https://developer.apple.com/support/psd2/) and then need to enter NemID etc. and when the User is moving back to the App, I'm getting this error

> A. “Purchase failed“ . B. The action could not be performed. C.
> SKErrorDomain error 0.

One thing to mention as I'm using `SwiftyStoreKit` POD for in-App purchase, and Transaction observer is already added in `AppDelegate` by calling `SwiftyStoreKit.CompleteTransaction(atomically: true)` as suggested by Apple(Transaction Observer).

> @sca(Strong Customer Authentication)  @EuropeanUnionregulation

If anyone faced same issue, any help would be great.

Here is the transaction failed screenshot after moving back to my app from strong authentication process:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed since January in Europe they're is a new regulation regarding to transaction security. You can find more details there : https://developer.apple.com/support/psd2/

Lot of apps undergo the same problem. Indeed, even if the documentation says that the transaction observer may receive a "failed" or "deferred" state we can expect that failed state will be only for iOS version that doesn't support the "deferred" state (so iOS versions <=7). Indeed the deferred state case is available since iOS 8.0.

However in reality even on iOS 14 the app transaction observer receive a failed state which results in an error pop-up displayed by a lot of app when they do the error management. Even if at the end the purchase succeed once user come back to the app (after validated the transaction with his bank app), it would be FAR better if iOS can return a "deferred" state to avoid an error pop-up while keeping the error management. And it will be more consistent with what it's happening.
In fact once the security process is completed your app's transaction observer must immediately receive a new transaction with a state purchased so in finality everything should be okay but with an unexpected error pop-up displayed for no real reason.

The only choice we have is let the error be displayed awaiting the end of process or discard the error management. I think the first choice is better and if an iOS version update the statement received it will be going fine without any app update.

Comment: if you look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox/testing_an_interrupted_purchase  item #10 doesn't get triggered (at least for me) during testing. So not only does the error comes up. the transaction is still considered a Fail, and no notification of a success if made to the transaction observer until the app is closed and restarted again (to background, then to foreground)